# How does result of `String.match` array contains index, group, etc.,?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I just got wondered how come the result of regexp match in Javascript returns an one-dimensional array with keyed indexes ?

```js
var str = "We will";

const result = str.match(/wi/);

console.log(Array.isArray(result));
console.log(result.index);
console.log(result.input);
```

Here how does the array is having string based keys("index", "input", etc.,). Is there way we can create an array like this in Javascript ?

Comment: Arrays are objects and their prototypes have methods on them. Consider reading about `prototypes`. (Note this does not completely answer why the returned match has those named properties)

Comment: Everything (with the exception of primitives thanks @Pointy), including Arrays, are objects and every Object can have arbitrary - user defined - properties assigned to it, whether that’s `arrayVariable.index`, `arrayVariable.input` or `arrayVariable.foo`.

Comment: Well everything that's not a primitive is an object.

Comment: `const arr = [1, 2]; arr.property = "PROP"; console.log(arr);`

Comment: One thing to note: while it's fine to add properties with non-numeric names to an array, they won't be included when you do `JSON.stringify()` and they won't be involved in any of the various Array iteration mechanisms. Also they won't affect the array `.length`. (I guess that's three things to note.)

Comment: It is a bit confusing as arrays typically are sequentially keyed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Arrays are just iterable objects in JavaScript. [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.

This means you can simply assign a property. Be careful though to not accidentally overwrite an existing property while doing so:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.propName = 42;

console.log(
  ...arr,
  arr.propName
);
```

Answer (score 3):

From ecmascript5 interface definition the match output is `RegExpMatchArray` or `null`, where `RegExpMatchArray` is defined as follows

```
interface RegExpMatchArray extends Array<string> {
  index?: number;
  input?: string;
}
```

if you need to do it in typescript you would define the interface in the exact same way and access/assign properties like you would access the objects'

if you don't need typescript you can skip the interface part and simply do

```js
const array = []

array.index = 1;
array.input = "test"

console.log(array.index, array.input)
```